# Seg Fault with struct referencing

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I've been searching all over to find a solution for my problem but I can't seem to find any. I'm doing a project for my class and I have a few segmentation faults, with a couple coming from this part of my code.

```
typedef struct {
    // Inherited fields from Expr.
    void ( *eval )( struct ExprTag *, Binary *dest );
    void ( *destroy )( struct ExprTag * );

    // Binary value it evaluates to.
    Binary *val;
} ValueExpr;

/** Eval function for ValueExpr. */
static void evalValueExpr( Expr *expr, Binary *dest ) {
    ValueExpr *this = ( ValueExpr * ) expr;

    andBinary( dest, this->val, this->val ); 
}
```

When running GDB and finding where the segmentation fault occurs and using a backtrace, I get this output:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040151e in andBinary (dest=0x6030a0, a=0x0, b=0x0)
    at Binary.c:170
#1  0x0000000000401ac3 in evalValueExpr (expr=0x603080, dest=0x6030a0)
    at Expr.c:22
#2  0x0000000000401eea in evalXorExpr (expr=0x603050, dest=0x603010)
    at Expr.c:200
#3  0x0000000000400f00 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2b8)
    at interpreter.c:272
```

As of my understanding, and I might be wrong, the seg fault is occuring when evalValueExpr is calling andBinary. with a=0x0 and b=0x0, does this mean this->val is null? I feel like I don't understand something if I can pinpoint where a seg fault is coming from and still I can't fix it.

To try and solve this problem, I tried initializing this->val with

```
this->val = makeBinary( dest->len );
```

which malloc's memory and everything. But when I try this, it says I'm dereferencing a pointer to an incomplete type. I looked that up and people kept talking about structs and how the OP made them. I'm not sure exactly what the problem for that is still though. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check for `NULL`. Always do it, some could say it's expensive but it's an old way of thinking, in the old days, it was expensive, noticiable, now  I don't think anyone can notice in most cases, there would of course be cases where you wouldn't want to do it. It's funnuy that you write your code so it doesn't compile with a c++ compiler.

Comment: It's a C course. And what exactly do you mean check for NULL? If I do so, then what? Apparently it is NULL, so it wouldn't work if I checked for it anyway. Is there something I can do besides checking for NULL?

Comment: *If I do so, then what?* that's the million dollar question everyone has in their minds :) Usually printing/logging a message like "this pointer is null but it should not be, so this function will not operate" is better than a segfault, though.

Comment: But what @iharob suggests is that after you populate your struct, check for null before calling the function that depends on the pointer being not null. That would indicate a problem with your populate function.

Comment: Put assert(p != NULL) after each function that returns a pointer that is assumed to be non-null. In your example this->val is NULL (#0 shows that), but it is unclear from where it comes. Assert is not proper way of handling this, but at least you will know where your invariants are broken.

Comment: Why do you cast the first argument of `evalValueExpr()` to `( ValueExpr * )`? This is very suspicious, and at best a symptom of terrible design.

Comment: I will do this assert() and also check for NULL in the evalValueExpr() and see what happens.

Comment: More generally, it's a pretty good idea to `assert()` conditions that can be false only if you have committed a programming error (i.e. your invariants), both for debugging purposes and documentary purposes.  There's a bit of an art, though, to exactly which assertions to make, and where.